# What objects are these: auto, mobile, automobile

Tags: word-meaning

Is it true that an `auto` is always a car, and a `mobile` is always a phone?

Is an `automobile` exactly the same as an `auto`?

Does `auto` / `automobile` refer to a car with automatic transmission, a self-driving car, or just any car in general? Put it another way, is a human-operated manual transmission car still an `auto` / `automobile`?

If an intelligent robot can move around, answer phone calls, drive cars, is that an `auto`, `mobile` or `automobile`?

Comment: *Mobile* is also an adjective. As in *I am very mobile.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *automobile* is any kind of car. The first cars were said to "move of themselves" because they were not horse-drawn, not because they didn't need a driver! (The last syllable is pronounced *beel* because the word originated in France.)

*Automobile* and *auto* are, I think, used more in American English than in Britain, where we originally called them *motor cars*, sometimes abbreviated to *motor* (but *autos, cars* and *motors* are all used in names of companies).

We British abbreviate *mobile phone* to *mobile* (Americans call them *cell phones*). A *mobile* can also be one of those decorations of small objects or cut-outs hanging on threads so that they turn round when the air moves.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that ... a mobile is always a phone?

Not always. This is also a mobile:

[image]